# Laravel Eloquent model events suddenly not called

Tags: laravel-5.3, php-5.6, event-dispatching

In my Laravel 5.3 application I am using several Eloquent model events (mostly `creating`). Up until a week ago they were working fine but suddenly as of today I notice that none of them seem to be firing anymore.

Debugging through the framework shows that they are indeed all added to the Dispatcher::listeners array, but I can't find the code that should step through and actually run them. Placing `die()` commands in the event callbacks do nothing, suggesting they are not acutally firing, and nothing I try seems to get them working.

Here is an example of one of them (this one is on a trait, but I am using a mix of traits and direct model):

`public static function bootUuidModel() {
        // On create, generate and assign a UUID
        static::creating(function (Model $model) {
            $model->setAttribute(self::getUuidFieldKey(), Uuid::uuid4()->toString());
        });
    }`

Anyone have any ideas as to why these are suddenly not running? I am using them across various models for various purposes and none of them seem to be running. Has anyone else using the framework experienced these problems as of late?

Thanks in advance

--UPDATE--

Okay so after some more investigation I've found that the problem is that the User object is for some reason booting BEFORE Laravel's  DatabaseServiceProvider is booted. DatabaseServiceProvider::boot() for some reason is where the event dispatcher is statically assigned to Model. So any booting in the User object is not registering the events with the dispatcher because the dispatcher doesn't exist yet. I am not booting the User object myself, does anyone know why Laravel would be doing this?

Comment: You should include where your `bootUuidModel` is being called. At the moment it's really hard to say what's wrong

Comment: These methods are never called explicitly in Laravel, Laravel should be picking it up and running with it. Not sure if I was clear in the question but the bootUuidModel() and other boot methods on other objects are being called themselves, and the callbacks added to the dispatcher, but none of the callbacks are running.

Comment: Yes, but you run bootUuidModel somewhere in your code, right? If not it's obvious events won't be fired

Comment: No i do not. Laravel should run it automatically as part of the model boot() method. As I say, my debugging shows that bootUuidModel() IS successfully being run.

Comment: Updated with more findings.